# Google Drive API scope : why I only have access to one?

Tags: curl, google-drive-api

This maybe a simple (stupid) question but at this point, I just do not get it.

I'm able to connect to the scope **drive.file** with :

```html
curl -d 'client_id='$idclient'' -d 'scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file' -d 'response_type=code' 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code'
```

But, when I want to connect to the scope **file**, I got **"error": "invalid_scope"** as result.

But as we can see on this screenshoot, this scope is enable with my app in Google OAuth page : 
[Scope permission in my account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfPWe.png)

So, how to connect to to the scope **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive** ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using "Oauth 2.0 for TV and Limited-Input Device Applications". As you can see in the top "Note" from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices):

> Important note: This OAuth 2.0 flow supports a limited set of scopes.

It leads us to the "Allowed Scopes" [section](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices#allowedscopes), and regarding the Drive API (Drive File API here), we only have this scope available:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the API I want to use is "restricted" : 
[OAuth 2.0 scope information for the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth)